# Recommended format to export 3D models for WebGL from a Java web app

Tags: java, webgl, three.js, java-3d

I have a web application that manipulates a 3D model on the server and allows the user to view the model. Using Java is a hard requirement for the web application, but the way the WebGL viewer interfaces with the application is still to be implemented.

What is the recommended format/method to export 3D models from Java to something easily usable in WebGL? You can assume I use the Java 3D library on the server side and Three.js on the client side.

Comment: My first thought was to load a Collada file through an Ajax request, but it appears that Collada export libraries in Java are rare, obscure and undocumented.

Comment: Maybe you could use obj?

Answer (score 1):

My preferred pipeline is export to JSON format and then convert to Float32Array in my loader. Collada will also work but because Collada allows things like a mesh to be described in many different ways Collada importers are usually finicky.

Comment: I have little experience with 3D object representation, so could you please elaborate on this or point me to an example that does this?