# Any way to do Java 3D model/scene exporting?

Tags: 3d, java

After asking my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040296/recommended-format-to-export-3d-models-for-webgl-from-a-java-web-app) I've assessed my possibilities to perform any *export* of 3D scenes and models from Java. My first concern was to find a format that was compatible within some restraints of our application, but after some further research it seems that there are very few export methods available to perform 3D exporting from Java in general. All examples I could find are either very old and unmaintained or export to propietary binary/XML formats that are incompatible with pretty much anything. Furthermore, none of the potential solutions I found is distributed as a library, but are part of a larger codebase.

What I'm looking for is a library that allows me to do scene and model manipulation in Java, and subsequently allows me to export that model to a file in a common format that is reusable (Collada, Wavefront, X3D even). Is there any library that I overlooked? Can I maybe use native code from the JNI to perform conversion? Are there any other solutions that I can use? Or is the best way to implement my own exporter for this?

Answer (score 1):

I used to use .obj for exporting from Java as it is an ASCII based format, most editors have conversion tools to support it (i.e. Maya and 3D Max).

I found an OBJ exporter library which is GPL as part of the sweethome3d project:
http://sweethome3d.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D/src/com/eteks/sweethome3d/j3d/OBJWriter.java?view=markup

Comment: That's some pretty useful code, but unfortunately the GPLv2 license is quite prohibitive in the context of my application.